# The expression evaluated to NULL, but a Boolean result is required

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

Below is the error message that I get when I fire the SQl query in Beeline.

```
The expression evaluated to NULL, but a Boolean result is required. Modify the error row disposition on the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row). The expression results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression result is an error.
```

At the first glance, it seems to be the straight forward issue of NULL values in the data. But below are other details on my observation.

Furthermore:

1) I am using BEELINE for the first time in my dev env. Before that, it was all HIVE CLI.

2) we have brought a table to HIVE through SQOOP, and since we wanted to convert the text format to ORC, so we had created an ORC table with 50 buckets and with the help of INSERT we transfer all the data to newly created ORC HIVE table.

3) there are 4 columns in my original HIVE table. I do not see any error while querying any of the columns. However, after we had pushed the data to the ORC HIVE table and now when I am querying 3 out of those 4 HIVE table I do not see any error. But when I am querying for this problematic column, then only I get the error. Below is the SQL query

```
select col_name from tbl_name limit 4; 

The output of the sql query on this particular table from the original HIVE table has below value

col_id is NULL
```

And we have also recognized that some of the values for this particular column has 365 chars. Below is the query for that

select max(length(col_name))from tbl_name;

It is a string type in both the HIVE tables.

4) we also created an internal HIVE table with demo data, and then pushed that data to an ORC table in BEELINE.In this case, when we are querying the ORC table we are not getting the issue.

```
 We are using Spark 2.1 server, and all our Hadoop components are on this server.
```

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where's the query?

Comment: its a simple query "select * from <tbl_name limit 3"

Comment: Add this above detail to the question please.

Comment: Show your beeline command. And if you're using Spark, then `spark-sql` command is also available for queries

Comment: Ok, there was some error in my explanation. I have formatted my original post with the new explanation